# how to configure a policy in gateway level to allow access for specific IP addresses to call APIs in wso2 APIM 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i want a solution to apply in gateway to allow access for specific IP addresses that only these IPs could call all APIs I created.in which step of Message Flow in the API Manager Gateway I must add this functionality : The handlers or Mediation extensions or
In sequence and out sequence?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit different from the old ones you asked, do you need a global policy to apply across all APIs? In that case, you can simply create [Deny Policies](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/rate-limiting/access-control/#denying-requests), which will block access to all the APIs for specific IP(s).

[image]

Going further you can even add a Firewall rule in the GW server to restrict access. (This is the most efficient and the most secure way, to block the connection even before reaching the server)

```
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange –src-range [START]-[END] -j DROP
```

Comment: thanx so much @ycr
actually I set invert to true for giving access to only some IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the solutions suggested by @ycr, let me also help you understand how/ where Handlers or Mediation extensions come into play.

- Handlers - this can be applied globally and this will engage for all the APIs which are deployed at the Gateway
- Mediations - these are API-specific and can be applied either for In-flow (request) or Out-flow (response) or Fault-flow (error). If you want to apply some custom business logic, depending on the path (in/ out/ error) you can apply custom mediations. However, you need to be a bit careful when applying mediations for each API as they will add extra latency to the APIs

Comment: thanx so much @Joy Rathnayake